# Swapping Pointers to pointers in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, swap

I have a question which involves calling a function with 2 parameters of a pointer to a pointer

```
int main(void)
{ ...
int *ptrp = &p, *ptrq = &q;
int **ppp = &ptrp, **ppq  = &ptrq;
swap_ptr(ppp,ppq);/* &ptrp, &ptrq passed */ 
/* to swap_ptr() */
return 0;
}

void swap_ptr(int **ptrA,int **ptrB)...
```

We have to swap the values of ptrp and ptrq, so does that mean in the swap_ptr function I just use *ptrA and *ptrB to swap them or is it some other pointer statement?

Thanks

Comment: You have the answer in your question, so I'm not exactly sure why it needed to be asked...

Comment: You can also use [XOR swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) for swapping pointers as well ...

Comment: @0x69 Fun fact: If you XOR swap two pointers that are the same, then they will both be set to a NULL pointer.

Comment: @Corbin
It depends on what you mean "same pointers". If it means same pointer variable - then yes, you can't swap same var - XOR swap must be applied to two variables which are stored at different memory addresses. However if by saying "same pointers" you mean different pointer variables which points to the same address - then NO, you can perfectly swap these two pointers. For example - below code is 100% valid in terms of XOR swap applicability =>

Comment: `void xorSwap (int **x, int **y) {
     if (x != y) {
         *x = (int*)((int)*x ^ (int)*y);
         *y = (int*)((int)*x ^ (int)*y);
         *x = (int*)((int)*x ^ (int)*y);
     }
 }

int main(void){
    int a = 7;
    int b = 11;
    int * pa = &b;
    int * pb = &b;

    printf("before %p %p / %d %d\n", pa, pb, *pa, *pb);
    xorSwap(&pa, &pb);
    printf("after  %p %p / %d %d\n", pa, pb, *pa, *pb);

    return 0;
}`

Comment: @0x69 True, but I was mainly just trying to illustrate in a brief manner that xor swapping is pointless.  A branch is going to be slower than just using a temporary variable, and I would imagine most compilers optimize the typical 3 line swap anyway.  The way I see xor: it's a cool trick, but not something that should be unleashed upon someone brand new to the three line swap without more explanation (which I delivered very badly).

Comment: I don't want to argue about XOR swap usefulness. However in some situations it can be useful. For example if you develop for microcontroller where available RAM is very limited and your C compiler can't generate XOR swap code ...

Comment: @0x69 I think most compilers would use a register for the temporary, not RAM.  Anyway, didn't mean to start a debate.  Just wanted to make sure that both you and the OP knew of that implication of xor swapping.  Considering the level of the question, the asker may have not known that, used it and run into some rather interesting bugs later.  And, in 99% of situations in which people bring up XOR swapping, it's not the right tool for the job, and the person mentioning it doesn't know about the possibility of a 0 pointer.  I wrongly assumed you fell into that :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `*ptrA` would refer to the variable `ptrp` in `main` and `*ptrA` would refer to `ptrq`. Swap these two values as you would for any other type and `ptrp` will now point to `q` and `ptrq` to `p`.

Since this sounds like it might be homework I'll let you come up with the three lines of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's all I needed to know

Answer (score 3):

It's the same concept as swapping anything:

```
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

In this case, you just happen to be swapping int* instead of int:

```
void swap(int** a, int** b)
{
    int* tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*ptrp refers to the value that the pointer is pointing to.
ptrp refers to the value of the pointer (the memory location)

swap_ptr could simply store one of the values in a tmp var and then swap the values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of new with these algorithms/techniques but I've had came up with this function;

```
function swap(int *p1, int *p2) {
  *p1 = *p1 + *p2;
  *p2 = *p1 - *p2;
  *p1 = *p1 - *p2;
}
```

You can test this function like that;

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

printf("%d %d\n", a, b); // 10 20

swap(&a, &b);

printf("%d %d\n", a, b); // 20 10
```

---

Here's a 3-step explanation for better understanding;

1. `*p1 = *p1 + *p2;`
   Add the values coming from **p1** *(*p1=10)* and **p2** *(*p2=20)* and store result on **p1** *(*p1=30)*.
2. `*p2 = *p1 - *p2;`
   We know result of the addition, calculate the old value of **p1** by subtracting current value of **p2** *(current *p2=20)* from value coming from **p1** *(*p1=30)* and store result on **p2** *(calculated *p2=10)*.
3. `*p1 = *p1 - *p2;`
   Since the value of **p1** *(*p1=30)* did not change on step 2 and we still have the old value of **p1** on **p2** *(*p2=10)*, we can divide **p2** into **p1** and store the result on **p1** *(calculated *p1=20)*

So as you can see we swapped two `int`s **without defining any temporary variable** and making pass-by-reference function call.

The reason of pass-by-reference is to minimize usage of memory. Because every pass-by-value call allocates new variables on the memory (to be deleted by GC or not) depends on how much parameter you've passed to the function.

Comment: -1 This is a very dangerous way to swap values, as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753278/swapping-2-pointers-with-inline-assembly

Comment: @JoeHass Why it is dangerous? As you can see in Update 1 there is no any problem with maximum value of `int`. What is the reason causing dangerous situation of `swap()` function?

Comment: You demonstrated that it would work **once**, which is much different from demonstrating that it will **always** work. Have you checked to see what the C language standard has to say about what happens when a signed integer overflows?