# Swapping 2 pointers with inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly

I'm developing with VS 2012, under 64 bit OS but output executable is 32 bit. Recently I was fiddling with swap algorithm. I did achieve it on C by;

```
void swap(int *p1, int *p2)
{
  *p1 = *p1 + *p2;
  *p2 = *p1 - *p2;
  *p1 = *p1 - *p2;
}
```

But I also want to do that with inline assembly *(__asm)*. I tried with these codes;

```
void aswap(int *p1, int *p2)
{
  __asm {
    mov ebx, p1
    mov ecx, p2
    mov p1, ecx
    mov p2, ebx
  }
}
```

and test the `aswap()` with these codes;

```
int a = 10;
int b = 200;

// print out the initial values
printf("%x(%d) %x(%d)\n", &a, a, &b, b);

aswap(&a, &b);

// finally print out the swapped values
printf("%x(%d) %x(%d)\n", &a, a, &b, b);
```

but the individual addresses and (consequently) the values are not changes.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

---

Update 1: @ouah

I've tested the `swap()` with these codes;

```
#include <limits>

int a = INT_MAX;
int b = INT_MAX - 1;
...
```

and here is my [screenshot](http://oi42.tinypic.com/jr8scy.jpg). Did I do something illegal with the memory?

Comment: What now? Are you swapping *pointers* or *integers*?

Comment: You swapped the contents of the parameters (the pointers), not what is pointed to.  What _should_ you be doing?

Comment: @KerrekSB i suppose swapping __pointers__ and __integers__ are same thing. When a variable's address changes doesn't that mean the value it points changes too?

Comment: Your `swap` function can invoke undefined behavior. Don't do that.

Comment: But that's not how functions work in C...

Comment: as @JeffMercado said, you're swapping the pointers. You should load their content and swap them

Comment: @dihejaso for example, if `*p1` is `INT_MAX`and `*p2` is `> 0`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The classic way to do this is to do an inline swap with several XOR operations. Assuming you have one pointer in EAX and the other in EBX the code would be:

```
XOR EAX, EBX
XOR EBX, EAX
XOR EAX, EBX
```

The result is that what was in EAX is now in EBX, and what was in EBX is now in EAX. Follow the bouncing bits to figure out how this works (and it's done entirely in registers, requiring no additional memory).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: This has zero advantage of `xchg eax,ebx` on any old or new x86 CPU.  `xchg` is 3 uops on modern Intel CPUs, same as this, but is lower latency.  But if you want to swap the contents of 2 memory locations, there's no need to exchange registers at all, just load both and then store to opposite locations.

Comment: The OP's problem is they swapped the C pointer locals, rather than the pointed-to locations, with their inline asm.